# How to execute heavy javascript code without the browser freezing?

Tags: javascript, html, scheduling, freeze

I had a page which executes heavy javascript code after loading. To prevent the page from freezing upon loading, I spaced the execution into batches with some "no-execution" time in between (using Timeouts), and things worked well.

Lately, I've had to add additional heavy javascript code which can execute upon client actions, yet these actions can occur even before the original heavy script is done executing. This time, spacing the action won't help, since at the "downtime" of one script the other can run and vice versa, which will cause the browser to freeze.

The problem is actually more complicated as there are multiple such actions, each executing a different heavy script, and each script sort of has a different "priority" as to how fast i'd like it to finish, compared to the other ones.

My question is, what is the common practice in such situations? I tried thinking of a way to solve it, but all I could think of was quite a complex solution which would pretty much be like writing an operating system in javascript - i.e., writing a "manager" code which executes every X time (using an "interrupt"), and chooses which "context to switch to" ( = which job should run right now), etc...

This however sounds pretty complicated to me, and I was hoping there might be other solutions out there. My problem sounds like one which I'd assume many people have stumbled upon before, so even if the only solution is what I suggested, I'd assume someone already wrote it, or there is some library support for this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**== EDIT ==**

by "heavy code", I mean for example the DOM manipulation of a great number of elements.

Comment: What type of "heavy" javascript?

Comment: It seems like you want to implement some sort of time-sharing threading mechanism in Javascript, which is, as far as I know, not something Javascript can do.

Comment: If something takes a long time to do on the front side ("front side" = JavaScript in your case), I generally sit down and carefully reconsider the design of my application.

Comment: here you can user jquery. Use jQuery ajax calls to execute heavy calls. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: bPratik: I apologise, I never paid as much attention to this aspect of the site as I should have, I'll make sure it doesn't happen again.

About the rest of the comments: I'm aware there is no threading mechanism in JS, which is why I'm talking about immitating an OS as it used to work on single core PCs.
Ajax calls aren't helpful for me in this case, as the majority of the work is DOM manipulation.

Comment: About this being a bad design - I don't think front side long-term jobs are necessarily indicative of bad design - I'm just trying to do something quite complicated, and so I'm trying to maximize what I can from the resources I got at my disposal - including the client.
Anyhow even if it is bad design, I'd be interested in this question for its theoretical aspect.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to think of defining your UI/Problem domain as a set of Asynchronous tasks. Here's some more insight http://alexmaccaw.com/posts/async_ui until I formulate a better answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to block your script you can use [web workers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_worker). See [MDN: Using web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_web_workers) for a good introduction. Note that web workers are still relative new and not supported by most browser.

However, if you want to support all browser *and* add some kind of priority for your "heavy scripts", you should define something yourself, e.g:

```
function WorkerQueue(this_argument){
    this.queue = [];
    this.this_argument = this_argument;
    this.priority = 1;
}

WorkerQueue.prototype.enqueue = function(callback){
    this.queue.push(callback);
}

WorkerQueue.prototype.dequeue = function(){
    return this.queue.splice(0,1)[0];   
}

function WorkerPool(){
    this.pool = [];
    this.status = "running";
    this.timeout = null;
}

WorkerPool.prototype.addWorker = function(this_argument){
    this.pool.push(new WorkerQueue(this_argument));
    return this.pool[this.pool.length - 1];
}

WorkerPool.prototype.nextTask = function(){
    var max_priority = 0;
    var max_priority_task = this.pool.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < this.pool.length; ++i){
        if(this.pool[i].priority > max_priority && this.pool[i].queue.length !== 0){
            max_priority = this.pool[i].priority;
            max_priority_task = i;
        }
    }
     // pool is empty or all tasks have an invalid priority  
    if(max_priority_task === this.pool.length)
        return;

    if(this.pool[max_priority_task].this_argument)
        this.pool[max_priority_task].dequeue().apply(this.pool[max_priority_task].this_argument);
    else
        this.pool[max_priority_task].dequeue().apply();

    if(this.status !== "running")
        return;
    this.timeout = setTimeout(function(t){return function(){t.nextTask();};}(this),1000);
}

var Workers = new WorkerPool();
var worker1 = Workers.addWorker();
worker1.enqueue(function(){
    console.log("Hello");
});
worker1.enqueue(function(){
    console.log("World");
});

var worker2 = Workers.addWorker();
worker2.priority = 2;
worker2.this_argument = worker2;
worker2.enqueue(function(){
    console.log("Worker 2 - changing priority");
    this.priority = .2;
});
worker2.enqueue(function(){
    console.log("Worker 2 - after change"); 
});

Workers.nextTask();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/N9Ny7/)

In this case, every "heavy script" is a worker, which is basically a queue of tasks. You create a new worker in the pool by using `addWorker` and add tasks to the specific workers queue by using `worker.enqueue(callback)`.

Comment: Since OP edited question to clarify "heavy code" to mean DOM manipulation, it gets interesting to figure out: how will WebWorker solve the problem? Send the innerHTML to WebWorker for off-DOM text manipulation?

Comment: @Azder: Either this (WebWorker can't manipulate DOM content), or use some kind of scheduling/custom worker pool. Btw - I read your linked article after I wrote my answer. While it is basically the same approach, using `setInterval` on heavy tasks is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: TBH I just provided the first google result I got, not that I read it :) I always use setTimeout. As for the DOM, just because I knew it can't manipulate DOM content I wrote "Send the innerHTML to WebWorker for off-DOM text manipulation" ;)